# How to add a block with recently added items?

Tags: magento

I know that I can display new products, but they have to be manually set as new...I would like a more automated approach.  Is there any way to show the most recently added items (that are visible to catalog)?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create add the following statement in the cms.xml file, in this section

```
<reference name="content">

<block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id=" " template="catalog/product/new.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: But on the new.phtml file do I just echo $collection, or how would I properly echo the number of items that are in setPageSize?

Comment: check out this link :http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Inchoo/extension/2513/featured-products

Comment: you download the extension from freegento.com. Just paste the key and then after downloading you can install it manually . it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You could create a block much like the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` block type. This block is used to retrieve all new products from your store and can be included via the XML layer. You will almost need an exact copy of the block, only the way how the product collection is loaded in `_beforeToHtml()` differs.

The collection you want to load within the `_beforeToHtml()` is then:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC') // either ASC or DESC
    ->setPageSize(4); // the amount of products you want to show
```

Comment: This is a bit above my head to figure out the next step.  I assume I put this code into a template (.phtml) file.  Can you elaborate a little further so I can fully implement this?